VB.NET: Cannot overwrite Excel file located in My Documents\Source
My program is used to save data read from the Excel file EmployeeMgmt.xlsx. I want to automatically close the form after successfully saving the data to MySQL, delete all lines except the title in the file EmployeeMgmt.xlsx and save the changes. upload this file. Even though I pointed to the correct path of the Excel file, the program created a new file right in the My Documents folder instead of overwriting changes to the original file located in Documents\Source
Documents
|__....
|__Source
|__EmployeeMgmt.xlsx
   Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        Try
            MySqlConn.Open()
            Dim savedRowsCount As Integer = 0

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvNew.Rows
                If Not row.IsNewRow AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells("col_ID").Value?.ToString()) Then
                    Dim employeeID As String = row.Cells("col_ID").Value.ToString()

                    Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee_tb WHERE employee_ID = '" & employeeID & "'"
                    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
                    Dim result As Object = COMMAND.ExecuteScalar()

                    If Convert.ToInt32(result) = 0 Then
                        Dim employeeName As String = row.Cells("col_Fullname").Value.ToString()
                        Dim gender As String = row.Cells("col_gender").Value.ToString()
                        Dim position As String = row.Cells("col_Position").Value.ToString()
                        Dim department As String = row.Cells("col_Department").Value.ToString()
                        Dim joinDate As String = row.Cells("col_JoinDate").Value.ToString()
                        Dim promoteDate As String = row.Cells("col_PromotionDate").Value.ToString()
                        Dim status As String = row.Cells("col_status").Value.ToString()

                        Dim queryInsert As String = "INSERT INTO employee_tb (employee_ID, employee_Name, gender, position, department, joinDate, promotionDate, status) VALUES ('" & employeeID & "', '" & employeeName & "', '" & gender & "', '" & position & "', '" & department & "', '" & joinDate & "', '" & promoteDate & "', '" & status & "')"
                        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(queryInsert, MySqlConn)
                        COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        savedRowsCount += 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            MySqlConn.Close()
            KryptonMessageBox.Show("Success" & savedRowsCount & , "Thông báo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

            Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application()
            Dim WorkbookPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Source", "EmployeeMgmt.xlsx")
            Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(WorkbookPath, Editable:=True) 
            Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet = DirectCast(Wb.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

            Dim rowCount As Integer = Ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            For i As Integer = rowCount To 2 Step -1
                Dim range As Excel.Range = DirectCast(Ws.Rows(i), Excel.Range)
                range.Delete()
            Next

            Wb.Save()
            Wb.Close()
            ExcelApp.Quit()

            Me.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            KryptonMessageBox.Show("Err: " & ex.Message, "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            If MySqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MySqlConn.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

Thanks a lots for your help! ^^
Dim WorkbookPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Source", "EmployeeMgmt.xlsx")
It should have overwritten the changes to the file following this path
P/s: I use Microsoft.Office.Interop to working with Excel in VB.NET

You may need a new MySqlConnection to perform the second query. Also, make sure to call .Dispose() on a database connection as soon as the code has finished with it. Make a new connection for every time you use it - it is made to work most efficiently that way.

Also, please see The proper way to dispose Excel com object using VB.NET?.
